# looping through a 2D Array diagonally

Tags: swift, loops, matrix

I'm writing a function thats supposed to loop though a 2D array diagonally(top left to bottom right). However, the code does not add to the outer while loop(i), it keeps it at 0. arr is 9X9

```
    var i = 0
    var j = 0

    while(i < arr.count-1){
        while (j < arr.count-1) {


            print("i = \(i) --- j = \(j)")
            if(i == j){

                sumDiagonalLeft += arr[j][i]

                print(sumDiagonalLeft)

                if(arr[j][i] == 1){
                    informationUsed += 1
                    arr[i][j] = 2
                }
            }

         j += 1

        }
        i += 1
    }
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
var array:[[Int]] = []

array.append([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
....
array.append([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

for (index, element) in array.enumerated(){
    for (innerIndex,innerElement) in element.enumerated(){
        print(innerElement) // you can do your logics here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it :)

Comment: happy to help you